# Getting form input/data in angular-ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to get the input values for a form I'm submitting and the data angular-ui is binding to the form is not what I expected. An example form:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" name="myform.firstname" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and in `submit()` I am just doing `console.log($scope.myform)`

I was expecting: `{ firstname: "sample" }` but I am instead getting:

```
{ $error: Object, $$success: Object, $pending: undefined, $name: "myform", $dirty: false, $pristine: true, $valid: true, $invalid: false, $submitted: true, $$parentForm: Object, 10 more… }
```

The input key and its value don't seem to be in here and even if I use a model, angular-ui is overriding the object on submit.

Comment: Read about [forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score -1):

Notice **name** and **ng-model** attributes on input field.
ng-model is important to do the data binding between angular scope and html elements.

```
<form name="myform" method="post" data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="myform.firstname" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is an angular-ui related issue, this will add a firstname object to myform however the firstname object looks similar to the one I added in my question. I just want to get the value from the input firstname in the myform object..